# Sampling Correlated Binary Values

Tags: sampling

Say I have two variables X, Y.  We progress through iterations 1 to i, and pull a binary TRUE/FALSE for each variable.  Each variable has it's own probability of getting TRUE each period P(X) and P(Y) (and each period is independent).

In addition, though, there is a probability of each variable getting a TRUE each period IF, in that period, another variable got a TRUE.  i.e. there exists a P(X) and a P(Y) draws TRUE, but there also exists a P(X|Y), P(Y|X) where P(X|Y) does not have to equal P(Y|X).

The question is, how can I sample accurately for both X and Y taking into account both P(X) and P(Y), as well as the contingent probabilities P(X|Y) and P(Y|X), such that the sampled values for X and Y in periods 1 to n end up having TRUEs at a frequency similar to P(X) and P(Y) for X and Y respectively?

Then, can that solution be expanded to the three variable problem?  Up to N number of variables.

**My first attempt was to sample against P(X) and P(Y) independently, and then each period IF one or the other was TRUE, test if the other should be changed to TRUE.  Clearly, though, this leads to TRUE frequencies that are greater than P(X) and P(Y) at the limit.

````r
##define P(X) and P(Y)
p_x <- .15
p_y <- .2

##let the columns be the contingency in the joint distribution (i.e. X in P(Y|X))
j_mat <- matrix(1, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
j_mat[1,2] <- .7
j_mat[2,1] <- .3

##we can then clearly sample independently for TRUEs at the correct probability

sample_length <- 1000

x_sample <- runif(sample_length, 0, 1) <= p_x
y_sample <- runif(sample_length, 0, 1) <= p_y

##but how to also factor in "j_mat"?
```
````

Comment: Can you describe more what `j_mat` is?

Comment: Three parameters are needed to determined your distribution. For example, P(A), P(B|A=0) and P(B|(B|A=1). or P{(0,0)}, P{(0,1)} and P{(1.0)}. So you need to find value of three parameters, then you can goto next step. Currently, you just give 2 parameter(0.15 and 0.2), and it is not enough to keep going.

Comment: j_mat is the matrix of contingent probabilities for the variables X and Y.  So the diagonals of the matrix are P(X|X) and P(Y|Y), which equal 1, and then the off diagonals are P(X|Y) and P(Y|X), which I have defined as 0.7 and 0.3

Answer (score 1):

Can you represent your dependence structure as correlation as your title suggests?

```
library(copula)
r <- 0.75 # correlation coefficient
p1 <- 0.15 # parameter for the first marginal binomial distribution (X)
p2 <- 0.2 # parameter for the second marginal binomial distribution (Y)
N <- 1000 # size of bivariate sample
cop <- normalCopula(r) # define the copula as Gaussian with correlation r
# define the population with binomial marginal distributions
P <- mvdc(cop,c("binom","binom"),list(list(size=1,prob=p1),list(size=1,prob=p2)))  
d <- rMvdc(1000,P) # sample from the bivariate population
```

Then "d" is the sample you want.

Edit: Thinking about this more, I have an idea that I concede is not complete.

You're playng with $P(X=x|Y=y)$ and $P(Y=y|X=x)$. However, you also are specifying $P(X=x)$ and $P(Y=y)$. If you specify three of them, Bayes' theorem gives you the fourth, so you can't tweak all four to your heart's content. The fourth is locked in once you specify three. Therefore, focus on only one conditional probability, let's say $P(Y=0|X=0) = p$. Then we also have that $P(Y=1|X=0) = 1-p.$

When we consider continuous correlated variables (say Gaussian marginals), we think that positive correlation means that X and Y are similar while negative correlation means that $X$ and $Y$ are opposite. For instance, with correlation of 0.9 and standard normal marginals, if we know that X is negative, we have a good idea that Y is also negative. In your case, you only have two values for each marginal variable. If $X$ is 0 and there a positive correlation between $X$ and $Y$, we expect $Y$ to be 0. That's related to $P(Y=0|X=0)$, except that we need some kind of transformation between $[0,1]$ where probability lives and $[-1,1]$ where correlation lives. What I'm proposing is that we transform between the two spaces using the linear function between (0,-1) and (1,1) where probability is in the first coordinate and correlation is in the second. That equation is $corr = 2*P(Y=0|X=0) -1$.

Something funky happens with discrete distributions where the copula isn't unique, so it makes sense to me that you might be able to represent any dependence between binary variables as a Gaussian copula.

Comment: I’ll work through this tomorrow, I like the idea.  I’m maybe a bit worried that my dependence structure isn’t quite correlation (admittedly an imprecise use of the term in the title) because the potential set for every relationship is [0,1].

Comment: @garm00 Do you say the set is [0,1] because it's a probability?

Comment: Correct yes that’s why

Comment: I like the transformation idea.  That reminds me in a way of creating a process for sampling from a multi-variate normal distribution for correlated normal errors.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
  p_x <- .15            means P(X=1) = 0.15
  p_y <- .2             means P(Y=1) = 0.20
  j_mat[1,2] <- .7      means P(X=1|Y=1) =0.70
```

We need $P(X=1|Y=0)$, which can be derived as:
$P(X=1|Y=0) = (0.15 - 0.2*0.7)/(1-0.2) = 0.0125$

So change

```
 x_sample <- runif(sample_length, 0, 1) <= p_x
 y_sample <- runif(sample_length, 0, 1) <= p_y
```

to

```
 y_sample <- runif(sample_length, 0, 1) <= p_y
 x_sample <- ((runif(sample_length, 0, 1) <= 0.7)*(y_sample=1) + 
             ((runif(sample_length, 0, 1) <= 0.0125)*(y_sample=0)
```

The meaning is if Y = 1 then get X from Bernoulli distribution with p =0.7, and if Y = 0 then get X from Bernoulli distribution with p =0.0125,

This method can be expended to the N variables situation, but need to specify 2$^N$ parameters.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit?  It looks like in your last snippet of code you're adding Boolean type results together?

Comment: I added the explanation into Answer.